# can't do return function in condewrite

Tags: python

I'm trying to understand the difference between returning and printing (I get the theory behind it, but when actually designing the code, I'm a bit lost as to how they're different from each other). I'm trying to repeat the middle character in an inputted string coupled with a repetition (int).

Why doesn't this work? Either in python idle or ion codewrite?

```
def mid_repeated (st, rep):
if len(st)%2==0: 
    middle = (len(st)/2) 
    center = (st[middle])*rep
    rep = "!"*rep
    return center + " " + str(rep)
else: 
    middle = (len(st)/2) 
    center = (st[middle])*rep
    rep = "!"*rep
    return center + " " + str(rep)
return mid_repeated
```

Comment: Do you have the body of the function indented properly in your actual code?

Comment: If you provide complete, correctly indented code, we probably can help you.

Answer (score 1):

As soon as a function returns something, it breaks. This is probably what you're wondering about.

However, I'm not exactly sure what you're trying to accomplish by returning the function itself. You may want to look at that again.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this helps at all, but return, returns something that can then be used outside of the function, where as print, just prints something...

Answer (score 0):

The difference between

```
def a(x):
    print x
```

and

```
def b(x):
    return x
```

is that they do different things. (No. Really?)

`a()` outputs the "thing" given as `x` and (implicitly) returns `None`.

`b()` does nothing but returning `x`.

The difference becomes clearer if you do

```
def examine(function):
    print "Calling:"
    ret = function(42)
    print "Call done."
    print "Function returned", ret
```

if I use this function to examine my functions,

```
examine(a)
```

prints

```
Calling:
42
Call done.
Function returned None
```

so you clearly see that the `42` is printed while the function runs and the function's return value is `None`.

OTOH,

```
examine(b)
```

prints

```
Calling:
Call done.
Function returned 42
```

which proves that the function prints nothing but giving the value provided back to the caller (as a return value), who is able to print it whenever appropriate, or do anything else with it.

Other point of view: `print` prints the given value immediately, `return` just gives it to the caller to do whatever is desired.